# Python throwing error when trying to pull order data via Shopify API

Tags: python, python-3.x, shopify

I am trying to play with this simple python script to pull order data from my shopify admin, but keep getting this error message (seems to be coming from line 6 as per terminal and sublime text) **TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting:**
Here is the script,

```
import shopify

API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
SHOP_NAME = 'Shop name goes here'
shop_url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
shop = shopify.Shop.current()

order = shopify.Order()
num = order.count()
print num
success = order.find()
print success
der.save()
print success
```

I am at a loss for what I am doing wrong and have tried changing line 6 every which way as this is apparently where the error is coming from (from what terminal/sublime text tells me.  Any input is appreciated, I am a complete newbie to Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
shop_url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME)
```

replace above line with

```
shop_url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/%s%s%s" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME)
```

The correct way to use traditional string formatting using the '%' operator is to use a printf-style format string (Python documentation for this **[here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)**):

> "'%s' is longer than '%s'" % (name1, name2)

However, the '%' operator will probably be deprecated in the future. The new PEP 3101 way of doing things is like this.

> "'{0}' is longer than '{1}'".format(name1, name2)

Comment: Accept answer if this helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Line shop_url = "...

Should in this format

shop_url = "https://%s:%s@SHOP_NAME" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD)

You are passing the shop_VAR and API,pass to the s% key to make the URL